Issue with Locating the Microsoft Azure CLI Application Despite It Being Visible in Entra Sign-in Logs
I cannot find the following application (Microsoft Azure CLI 04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46) in my Azure tenant by any method imaginable.
First, I used a locally installed Microsoft CLI to log in to my tenant.
Azure cli logon 
Then, I checked the sign-in logs and saw the following values:
Entra ID signin logs
The values match the Microsoft documentation: Verify first-party apps sign-in.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/entra/entra-id/governance/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in
I checked all Enterprise apps, but I could not find a match.
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.Read.All", "Application.Read.All"
Get-MgServicePrincipal -All -Property * | Where-Object {$_.Displayname -like "*CLI*"}
DisplayName Id AppId
----------- -- -----
SharePoint Online Web Client Extensibility Isolated 19fb6d6a-0953-4e59-826b-4ebac1c8133a 3bc2296e-aa22-4ed2-9e1e-946d0…
Azure Multi-Factor Auth Client                      2b027fbc-b813-47fc-b88b-c2fa164e45f8 981f26a1-7f43-403b-a875-f8b09…
OCaaS Client Interaction Service                    63c2caae-86f8-43e6-9e4e-b3647d63a13a c2ada927-a9e2-4564-aae2-70775…
OfficeClientService                                 9c877073-a359-4396-b424-d1cf0408b096 0f698dd4-f011-4d23-a33e-b3641…
SharePoint Online Web Client Extensibility          bbde190f-2f8f-4399-9a33-cb8a6f1891cf 08e18876-6177-487e-b8b5-cf950…
Also, the GUI does not return anything:
Enterprise application in the GUI filtered
Even using the deprecated method via the AzureAD module does not return anything:
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Import-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

 (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true) | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*CLI*"}

ObjectId                             AppId                                DisplayName                                        
--------                             -----                                -----------                                        
19fb6d6a-0953-4e59-826b-4ebac1c8133a 3bc2296e-aa22-4ed2-9e1e-946d05afa6a2 SharePoint Online Web Client Extensibility Isolated
2b027fbc-b813-47fc-b88b-c2fa164e45f8 981f26a1-7f43-403b-a875-f8b09b8cd720 Azure Multi-Factor Auth Client                     
63c2caae-86f8-43e6-9e4e-b3647d63a13a c2ada927-a9e2-4564-aae2-70775a2fa0af OCaaS Client Interaction Service                   
9c877073-a359-4396-b424-d1cf0408b096 0f698dd4-f011-4d23-a33e-b36416dcb1e6 OfficeClientService                                
bbde190f-2f8f-4399-9a33-cb8a6f1891cf 08e18876-6177-487e-b8b5-cf950c1e598c SharePoint Online Web Client Extensibility         

I also tried to filter by Id instead of by display name, but without success.
My question is: How can I find this application? Based on the sign-in logs, it should exist in my tenant.

It seems to be a common issue where certain service principals or apps don't appear in some tenants. A solution that worked involves using the Azure CLI to manually create the service principal. You can run the command: az ad sp create --id 04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46 The issue is also discussed here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/28628 Thank you @jitter for pointing into the right direction.

Hi @HelloWorld Any update on the issue?

Note that, Microsoft Azure CLI is first-party Microsoft application with app ID as 04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46.
In some tenants, this service principal might not appear in Enterprise applications tab like this:

In such cases, you can make use of below CLI command to manually create service principal:
az ad sp create --id 04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where "Microsoft Azure CLI" application appeared successfully as below:

